# Why are the distances different?

Tags: html, sass

I have these codes in SCSS and HTML (Astro)

```html
<header class="mainHeader">
        <a href="/"><img src="/images/mainLogo.png" alt="Логотип " id="headerLogo"></a>
        <div id="links">
                <a href="/products">Продукты</a>
                <a href="/sale">Акции</a>
                <a href="/contacts">Контакты</a>
        </div>
</header>
```

```scss
.mainHeader {
    background-color: var(--white);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    #links {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 10%;

        a {
            color: $green;
            text-decoration: none;

            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 550;
            font-size: 1.3rem;

            margin-right: 50px;

            &:last-of-type {
                margin-right: 0;
            }
        }
    }

    #headerLogo {
        position: relative;
        height: 3em;
        margin-top: 0.8em;
        margin-bottom: 0.7em;
        left: 10%;
    }
}
```

But distance between left side and image is MUCH smaller than distance between buttons and right side ([I hope you can see image well](https://imgur.com/Zlm3huI)).

Why does it happen and how do I fix it?

The distance is equal only if I make

```scss
...
    #headerLogo {
        position: relative;
        height: 3em;
        margin-top: 0.8em;
        margin-bottom: 0.7em;
        left: 75%; /* Changed from 10% to 75% */
    }
```

Comment: `#links {margin-right: 10%}` is causing the issue. To avoid this, the easiest way would be to add a `padding` to the parent and remove the `margin` on both #links` and `#headerLogo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it! I made a div with links AND image, than moved `margin-left` and `margin-right` to it. Code:

```scss
.mainHeader {
    background-color: $white;

    #header {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-right: 10%;
        margin-left: 10%;

        #links {
            margin-left: auto;

            a {
                color: $green;
                text-decoration: none;

                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 550;
                font-size: 1.3rem;

                margin-right: 50px;

                &:last-of-type {
                    margin-right: 0;
                }
            }
        }

        #headerLogo {
            position: relative;
            height: 3em;
            margin-top: 0.8em;
            margin-bottom: 0.7em;

        }
    }
}
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">
        <div id="header">
                <a href="/"><img src="/images/mainLogo.png" alt="Логотип " id="headerLogo"></a>
                <div id="links">
                        <a href="/products">Продукты</a>
                        <a href="/sale">Акции</a>
                        <a href="/contacts">Контакты</a>
                </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of increasing the left property of #headerLogo to 75%, which looks like  more of a workaround than a solution, try applying a similar margin technique to the #logo. This should balance the space on both sides in a more responsive and flexible manner:

```
.mainHeader {
    
    justify-content: space-between; // Change from 'center' to 'space-between'

    #headerLogo {
        ...
        margin-left: 10%;
    }

    #links {
        ...
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
}
```

By setting justify-content: space-between; on .mainHeader, you distribute the space between the logo and the links equally. Then, adjusting the margins of both #headerLogo and #links ensures symmetrical padding from the edges of the header.

Comment: No, sadly didn't work, same as was. As I understand, these 10% are counted from <img> element, but I don't know why

Answer (score -1):

Ah, OK, so the margin-left: 10%; and margin-right: 10%; values in your SCSS are calculated based on the width of the parent element. This CSS rule is pushing #links to the right edge of its containing block (.mainHeader) because it sets the left margin to automatically occupy the available space. This will be why there is more space on the right side of #links compared to the left side of #headerLogo.

```
.mainHeader {
   background-color: var(--white);
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between; /* Use space-between to evenly distribute items */
}

#headerLogo {
   position: relative;
   height: 3em;
   margin-top: 0.8em;
   margin-bottom: 0.7em;
   margin-left: 10%; 
}

#links {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: 10%;

   a {
      color: $green;
      text-decoration: none;

      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 550;
      font-size: 1.3rem;

      margin-right: 50px;

      &:last-of-type {
         margin-right: 0;
      }
   }
}
```

So this SCSS code uses justify-content: space-between; in .mainHeader to evenly distribute child elements, which should give equal spacing on both sides of #headerLogo and #links.

Comment: Nope, didn't work neither. It is the same code, isn't it?